# How to filter web application data sent to client

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, jackson

In web application how do you filter data that should be sent to client?

Let's say I'm implementing a comment system in single page application. I need to show all comments and make 'Edit' button available for comment owner. My domain model consist of User and Comment classes

```
class User {
    String id;
    String name;
    String password;
    String email;
}

class Comment {
    User owner;
    String text;
}
```

The flow is the following: user requests for page with comments, I get comments from DB, serialize them to JSON and send to client. In this case the user can see email and password field of other users which is not acceptable. I can annotate these fields with @JsonIgnore. But if I have some kind of profile page then user won't be able to see his current email because it is ignored.

I discovered two ways of solving the issue

1. Annotate fields with @JsonView;
2. Use DTO pattern and create UserProfileView, CommentOwnerView classes.

The second way looks a little bit more preferrable IMHO. I guess it produces more overhead but looks clear and straightforward. The first one looks nice too though.

Which one is more preferrable, what do you think? Is there another way maybe?

Comment: There is one more option [JsonFilter](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter)

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600717/use-jsonview-to-exclude-like-jsonignore-with-play-frameworks-default-json-wr/26606140#26606140)