# Exclude fields from Ebean to save it in DB

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I have a **User** bean :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    public int id; 

    public String name; 
    public String username; 
    public String email; 
    public String password; 
    public Timestamp inscriptionDate; 
    public Timeline timeline;
}
```

Which I save in database with play like this:

```
User user = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();
user.save();
```

But I do not want to save the *Timeline* User's fields.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

**EDIT 1** 
I tried `@Transient` on the wanted field, bt no effect.

**EDIT 2** 
Here is the **Timeline** class :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Timeline {

    public SortedSet<Event> events;
    public String familyName;    

    public Timeline(String familyName)
    {       
        this.events=new TreeSet<Event>(Event.getEventsComparator());
        this.familyName=familyName;
    }
// some other methods 
}
```

And here is the User class :

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

@Id
public int id;  
public String name; 
public String username; 
public String email; 
public String password; 
public Timestamp inscriptionDate;
@Transient
public Timeline timeline;

public User(){}

public User(String name, String email, String username, String password){
    this.name = name; 
    this.email = email; 
    this.username = username; 
    this.password = password; 
}

// Other methods ... 
}
```

**EDIT 3** 
I displayed my user in db using this method :

```
public static Result getUsers(){
        List<User> users = new Model.Finder(String.class, User.class).all(); 
        return ok(toJson(users)); 
    }
```

An I think this i why I always have a `null` field for `timeline`. Timeline is actually **not** saved in DB, am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

I use @Transient in my Application with success.

Perhaps is an import problem :

```
import javax.persistence.Transient
```

not

```
import java.beans.Transient
```

**Edit 2**

Exclude field in DB : @Transient works

Exclude field in json : It exist few solutions, [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600717/use-jsonview-to-exclude-like-jsonignore-with-play-frameworks-default-json-wr) is one

Comment: Is it possible to get more code, entire classes (Timeline, User) by example ?

Comment: I edited my code in the question (see Edit 2). Thank's !

Comment: I copy the codes in my project and it's work. Even without @Transient.

Comment: In my project, for saving timeline in User, Timeline class must extends Model and @ManyToOne annotation must be present on field timeline in User class

Comment: Can you add part of 1.sql file concerned

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the problem.See Edit 3 :)

Comment: You never look at your database? That the field can be found in your json is not related

Comment: Thing is (please, don't laugh) : I haven't yet found the way to access to the DB manager with play (very few docs)

Comment: Ok. I can hereby confirm that I have no timeline into my DB. Huge thank you for your help @Karim !!

Answer (score 0):

Binding data directly from request (form) to database entity class is a security breach. You would want to bind it to `POJO` class, perform validation if necessary and then populate your `User.class` with request data yourself.

Comment: I did it, but same problem, it save a timeline. So, I really have to explicitly declare the timeline as "non-savable"